# How to get elements from Active Record which have a certain attribut value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Model `Question` which has a `question_id: integer` attribut. If I'm getting the records inside my controller I'm doing

```
@questions = Question.all
```

but how can I query all records where `question_id` has a certain value like `10`. Something like:

```
@questions = Question.all{:question_id => 10}
```

Thanks

Comment: Like this: `Question.where(question_id: 10)`? Probably worth the read - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html.

Comment: You're welcome! Go ahead and accept @IvanSelivanov's answer though, so people know the question has been answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@questions = Question.where(question_id: 10)
```

A useful link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html